# Template syntax question regarding member variable offsets

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

I'm using Luabind to integrate LUA into one of my projects, and the following thing struck me as odd (I'm a self taught beginner)

```
  template <class C, class D, class GetPolicies, class SetPolicies>
        class_& def_readwrite(
            const char* name
          , D C::*mem_ptr
          , GetPolicies const& get_policies
          , SetPolicies const& set_policies
        )
```

this function takes a string and a pointer to a member field, I get that, what confuses me is the order here.

```
D C::*mem_ptr
```

I expected D::C *, since "&foo::bar" into  "foo bar:: *" ...looks very odd to me.
What is the logic behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you substitute `D` and `C` with actual types, it makes sense:

```
struct Test{
  int member;
};

typedef int Test::*memptr;
//      ^^^ ^^^^
//       D   C
memptr p = &X::member;
```